color of text changes to white in dark theme
Text(
           style = profileItem
           text = priceStyle(order.total!!),
           modifier = Modifier
                      .padding(start = 2.dp),
     )

val profileItem = TextStyle(
    color = Color.Black,
    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.yekanbakhfanum_semibold)),
    fontSize = 14.sp,
    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    textDirection = TextDirection.Rtl
)

I am using the code above so I want the text color to be black despite the fact that user phone is in dark mode or not but still it's color changes to white in dark theme
I deleted my darkColors and the theme related to it also copied the lightColors and used them as dark theme too but none of them worked


Create text color for default theme in res/values/colors.xml
<resources>
    <color name="myTextColor">#000000</color>
</resources>


Create text color for night mode in res/values-night/colors.xml
<resources>
    <color name="myTextColor">#000000</color>
</resources>


Use myTextColor color resource in your Text.
val textStyle = TextStyle(
     color = myTextColor,
     // ...
)




What is your app theme's parent? I believe it is DayNight.
Make it:
<style name="Theme.Composeprojects" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />


To cancel dark mode you should do something like this in your Theme.kt file:
@Composable
fun AppTheme(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors = lightColors(
        primary = AppColors.DarkCyan,
        background = Color.White,
        surface = Color.White,
    )

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = shapes,
        content = content
    )
}

You should only use lightColors method.
